# BT Wifi swamps my signal

Tags: wireless-networking

Recently I have seen, with Inssider wifi software, BT wifi signals, 4 SSID's, in my area that are stronger than the signal from my own Wifi router. Frequently, even inspite of me changing my channel, I am unable to connect because the BT wifi is swampping my reception. Can this be right?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you're in the United Kingdom in case some forum users from other countries don't know what you mean when you mention "BT" (British Telecom).

Comment: Shield your attic and walls with material that can block the BTWiFi signal. Your WiFi won't work outside of your house, but should work just fine inside. http://www.instructables.com/answers/How-can-I-block-wifi-signals/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the channel used by your router. There are ~13 channels to choose from. Try and pick a channel that no other routers are sharing - and, if possible, 2 or more channels from another wifi signal.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, I have changed channel - frequently - but it makes little difference. Do you know where BT site their Wifi antenna? I also have the additional problem of neighbours with Wifi routers sited adjacent to the walls of my house, again with stronger signals than mine....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a BT Homehub as your router then these will - by default - have the OpenZone and BTFon SSIDs active as well as your home  SSID.

It is possible to turn off the OpenZone and BTFon SSID broadcasts.  This will at least mean that your own signal is stronger than any other OpenZone signal in your neighbourhood.

Log onto the router, usually by entering "bthomehub" into your browser (some newer hubs may vary - check the manual) and select the option to Opt Out of BTFon from the configuration settings.